# Dynamic images with angular and ngx-gallery

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have integrated [ngx-gallery](https://github.com/lukasz-galka/ngx-gallery) into my project.

My component now looks like this:

```
<div class="page-content">
 <ngx-gallery [options]="galleryOptions" [images]="galleryImages" fxFlex="70"></ngx-gallery>
 <button (click)="updateGallery()">CLICK!</button>
</div>
```

I am trying to use the following function in order to update my gallery:

```
  updateGallery(): void {
      this.galleryImages = this.galleryImagesCache.slice(0, Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 1)) + 1);
  }
```

However, it appears once the ngx-gallery component is initialized, it will not update it's contents. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you initializing the in NgxGalleryModule  in  `constructor`?

Comment: @SumitRidhal, no I am not, when I do initialize it in the constructor, what is the next step? Thanks

Comment: Probably this lib just do setting in OnInit and does not process onChanges. Open an issue on github for this lib

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova, thanks for the suggestion - he looked into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this lib just do setting in OnInit and does not process onChanges. Open an issue on github for this lib.

Comment: Thanks, reached out to the dev and he implemented it right away. Kudos for real life experience